# PHP Subdomain session disappearing

Tags: php, session, subdomain

**index.php**

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_GET['n'])) {
  $_SESSION['foo'] = "bar";
  header("Location: /index.php?n=D");
}

echo "FOO: ".$_SESSION['foo'];
```

This page `index.php` is used in a subdomain. The subdomain is a folder in the root domain, i.e.

```
 - WWW
    - SUB DOMAIN
      - index.php
```

The session variable `foo` is set on page call, then checked after a redirect header - and it's gone.

I've tried:

- `ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.example.com');`
- Various combinations of `session_set_cookie_params()`
- Location: *http://subdomain.example.com*
- Tearing my hair out

but nothing seems to be working.  Seems like a very simple problem - can someone help me find my lost cookie / session / variable ?

**EDIT**

`var_dump(session_get_cookie_params())` yields

```
array(5) { ["lifetime"]=> int(0) ["path"]=> string(11) "/" ["domain"]=>
 string(23) ".example.com" ["secure"]=> bool(false) ["httponly"]=> bool(false) }
```

My URL has a dash `-` in it (my-example.com).  Could this be the problem?

Also tried setting `session_name()` before params. Still not working.

Comment: And what is actually in cookies? What domain does session variable cookie belong to?

Comment: Thanks for the response - sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say.  All that should be in the cookie is the session ID info, and my variable `foo`.  I've made the cookie visible to all domains with `.example.com` so it should be visible on this one. I've tried changing the `path` to the subdomain, all with no luck.

Comment: Ahh just found the problem after five hours. `session.save_path` was not set in my server.  Will do more research and write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After five hours of trying myself, I finally contacted my hosting provider and they had a look.

The verdict? `session.save_path` in `php.ini` had not been set.  The script above is now running properly.

If someone cares to elaborate on the whys and hows and whatnot, I'll be happy to give them the solution, otherwise I'll have to accept my own.